# Get recycler view items position by item tag?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing a chat application like what's app, whenever i receive a message  i want to update the number of unread messages for that particular chat.

I'm using recycler view for displaying contacts, now when i receive a push notification for chat i need to update the row's unread message count like below.

[image]

If user clicks on any of the item i can get the view but can i get the recycler view item dynamically

If i know the position i can get but here user wont click on any of the row, i need to update the particular row dynamically. I thought to set tag for each row but i don't know how to get the row based on its tag.

Thanks in advance

updated code:

```
public class JobsFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobsFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter.JobsViewHolder> {


    private List<PdJob> jobs;


    public  JobsFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter(List<PdJob> jobs){
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }


    public void sortByCustomerName(){
        Comparator<PdJob> myComparator = new Comparator<PdJob>() {
            public int compare(PdJob obj1,PdJob obj2) {
                if(obj1.userName != null && obj2.userName != null){
                    return obj1.userName.compareTo(obj2.userName);
                }
                    return 0;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(jobs,myComparator);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void sortByModel(){
        Comparator<PdJob> myComparator = new Comparator<PdJob>() {
            public int compare(PdJob obj1,PdJob obj2) {
                if(obj1.jobCarName != null && obj2.jobCarName != null){
                    return obj1.jobCarName.compareTo(obj2.jobCarName);
                }
                    return 0;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(jobs,myComparator);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public JobsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View partnerTypeView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        JobsViewHolder jobsViewHolder = new JobsViewHolder(partnerTypeView);
        return jobsViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final JobsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final PdJob pdJob = jobs.get(position);
        holder.mView.setTag(pdJob.jobId);
        holder.consumerName.setText(pdJob.userName);
        holder.jobIdNumber.setText(pdJob.jobId);
        holder.consumerVehicle.setText( pdJob.jobCarName);
        holder.typeOfService.setText(pdJob.serviceType);
        holder.registrationNumber.setText(pdJob.regNo);
        if(NotificationManager.checkJobChatExists(pdJob.jobId)) {
            holder.textNumber.setText("" + NotificationManager.getJobNotificationCount(pdJob.jobId));
        }
        else {
            holder.textNumber.setText("0");
        }
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //screen navigation
            }
        });

        holder.chatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //screen navigation
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobs.size();
    }

    static class JobsViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @InjectView(R.id.registration_number)
        TextView registrationNumber;

        @InjectView(R.id.job_id_number) TextView jobIdNumber;

        @InjectView(R.id.consumer_name) TextView consumerName;

        @InjectView(R.id.consumer_vehicle_model) TextView consumerVehicle;

        @InjectView(R.id.text_number) TextView textNumber;

        @InjectView(R.id.job_type_of_service) TextView typeOfService;



        @InjectView(R.id.chat_button) ImageView chatButton;
        public final View mView;

        JobsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Are you keeping a list of your views? If so you can get at the view from your tag by accessing that index in your list? Can you post some code.

Comment: in setupRecyclerView u might have registered an adapter, then in that adapter u might have an holder class, there u can set an onclick listener for the view and in onclick method u get the item clicked. say cv is my cardview   cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);  cv.setOnClickListener(this); public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(v == cv)
            {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Name ==>"+personName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }}

Comment: @Mahalakshmi the solution you have given is when user clicks on the adapter(s) view, but this question is about updating one of the items in the recyclerview adapter with chat count without user interaction.

Comment: @vguzzi , I have a recyclerview defined with adapter set to it. for your comment   "you can get at the view from your tag by accessing that index in your list" . How can i get the view from tag without index value?? I'm not going to have index value as user won't be clicking on the view, i want to dynamically update view(s) value when i receive a message for chat. I hope you understood my problem

Comment: notify ur adapter once u receive a message /chat. and put conditions for ur    view item display, say if unread msg i save as 1-for it a separate view and if read say 0 then some other view .for each item ids if u get the response from server about read or unread then u can change accordingly dynamically without user interaction.

Comment: Yes i Can do notify adapter but with that approach the adapter needs to get rendered everytime a notification is sent. I want to update particular row not complete adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know which view the new data is intended to be for you will have to re-calculate your views by setting them up again then calling.

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It's hard to give you a better answer than this without a code example to see how your adapter is currently working.

EDIT:

If you receive a PdJob ID in your push notification you could do something like this:

```
public void updateJob(int jobId) {
    notifyItemChanged(getPdJobPosition(jobId));
}

private int getPdJobPosition(int jobId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
        if (jobId == jobs.get(i).getId()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG!! this will impact app performance severly. I know that i can do with notifyDataSetChanged(); but it is costly approach. Any one with a better solution?

Comment: "It's hard to give you a better answer than this without a code example to see how your adapter is currently working."

Comment: @Manikanta I've updated my answer, if you are getting something else through from the push and not an ID then let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: Hey thank you, but my model doesn't have any field for count value. So with position i will get view and find the count textview and increment the previous count value and finally call notifyitemchanged for that particular row . Is my approach added with your solution a better one?

Comment: And yes i am getting jobId from notifications

Comment: When you call `notifyItemChanged` your `onBindViewHolder` will get called again for that view. Is this the code which sets the unseen message count? 
if(NotificationManager.checkJobChatExists(pdJob.jobId)) {
            holder.textNumber.setText("" + NotificationManager.getJobNotificationCount(pdJob.jobId));
        }
        else {
            holder.textNumber.setText("0");
        }

If so then `holder.textNumber.setText("" + NotificationManager.getJobNotificationCount(pdJob.jobId));` should increment it for you I assume? If not then you will have to increment the modal value first.